# Copy/Move whole folder but with certain extentions

Tags: wildcards, file-copy

I have a backup copy of my site located in /tmp/backup and want to copy it to /home/mysite/public_html
But my aim is to copy only the .php files (with nested folders) and replace.

If I don't have nested folders i simply do `cp /tmp/backup/*.php /home/mysite/public_html`

But how i can do it for the whole site with many folders?

Comment: man cp and look for -r.

Comment: remember certain extension only in all files

Comment: why the hell i am getting negatives on logical questions!?

Comment: @TDSii You get automatic downvotes when people vote to close as off-topic; they're not migrated with the post, so you're at +2 here

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /tmp/backup
find . -name '*.php' | cpio -pmud /home/mysite/public_html
```

Answer (score 1):

On recent versions of bash, you can enable globstar (`shopt -s globstar`), and then do:

```
cd /tmp/backup
tar cvf - **/*.php | tar xvf - -C /home/mysite/public_html
```

** matches all files, dirs and subdirs

I'm using `tar` here because it preserves the directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX tools, use [pax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_%28Unix%29) (the POSIX replacement to [tar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14250/copy-move-whole-folder-but-with-certain-extentions/14253#14253) and [cpio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14250/copy-move-whole-folder-but-with-certain-extentions/14254#14254)):

```
cd /tmp/backup
find . -name '*.php' | pax -rw -pp /home/mysite/public_html
```

With zsh, first create the target directories, then copy the files. Put the first two lines in your `~/.zshrc`.

```
autoload zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C' zln='zmv -L'
cd /tmp/backup
mkdir -p **/*.php(e\''REPLY=/home/mysite/public_html/${REPLY:h}'\')
zcp '(**/)(*.php)' '/home/mysite/public_html/$1$2'
```

(Here, zsh has no advantage over the standard method, because `zcp` doesn't have a way to create target directories as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`cp /tmp/backup/*/*.php /home/mysite/public_html/`

Comment: try or sure? can anyone verify this please

Comment: -1 This won't work because it does not preserve directories. It will copy all files into the same directory.

Answer (score -1):

**updated the answer**
run the below command one after other.
**this will preserve the directory structure also**:

```
cp /tmp/backup /home/mysite/public_html
find /home/mysite/public_html -not -name "*.php"|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: i guess u mean ./tmp/backup/
edit: after trying ur command it fully corrupted my site by saving all files in the same directroy

Comment: if thats the case then you need to mention in the question clearly that you also need the same directory structure to be copied.the question looks vague to answer.

Comment: why the hell a -1 for this answer?

Comment: This answer is **WRONG AND DANGEROUS**. The first thing the `find` command will print out is `/home/mysite/public_html`, which `rm` will dutifully remove. Even if the `find` command was amended to exclude directories, any file that wasn't the result of the copy would be deleted, which isn't in the requirement. Furthermore, `xargs` expects an input format that `find` doesn't produce, so if there are any files with special characters (whitespace or `\'"`) in their names, `xargs` will pass unintended names to `rm`, and files anywhere on the system may be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

```
find /tmp/backup/ -name "*.php" | xargs -I % cp % /home/mysite/public_html
```